# Выборка из mysql по клику на странице

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код. Он выполняет запрос из базы на все записи с постраничной навигацией.

```
include('config.php');

$lim = "9";

@$page = $_GET['page'];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM music");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$posts = $row[0];
$str = ceil($posts / $lim);

if (empty($page) or $page < 0)
    $page = 1;

if ($page > $str)
    $page = $str;

$start = $page * $lim - $lim;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM music ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $start, $lim");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$artist = $myrow['artist'];

do {
    printf("
    <div id='mp3'>
    <h5 style='margin: 20px;'>" . $myrow['artist'] . " - " . $myrow['title'] . "<a href='" . $myrow['link'] . "'>Скачать</a></h5>

    </div>
    ");
} while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));

echo '<div id="navi_n"><a href=?page=' . ($page - 1) . '>Назад</a>  ';

$i = 1;

while ($i <= $str) {
    if ($i == $page) {
        echo '<strong><a href=?page=' . $i . '>' . $i . '</a></strong> ';
    }    
    else {
        echo '<a href=?page=' . $i . '>' . $i . '</a> ';
    }    
    $i = $i + 1;    
}

echo '  <a href=?page=' . ($page + 1) . '>Вперед</a></div>';
```

Не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы поле `artist` было ссылкой, при нажатии по которой происходила выборка из базы только по его имени? Так же необходимо сделать выборку записей по месяцам, т.е. пользователь кликает на "Январь" ему показываются все записи за Январь, конечно поле date есть. Уже третьи сутки парюсь :(

update1: не в курсе, чей урок :) Да, ошибка. Только еще начинаю узнавать php, так что нет поводов для усмешек :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

создаём файл findmusic.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['artist']))
{
     $mus_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM music WHERE artist='$_REQUEST[artist]'");
     if($mus_q)
{
  echo "<table border=1>";
  echo "<tr><td>Артист</td><td>Песня</tr>";
  // Так как запрос возвращает несколько строк, применяем цикл
  while($mus_art = mysql_fetch_array($mus_q))
  {
    echo "<tr><td>".$mus_art['artist']."&nbsp;</td><td>".$mus_art['music']."</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
else
{
  echo "<p><b>Error: ".mysql_error()."</b><p>";
  exit();
}
}
?>
```

А в вашем файле изменяем:

```
<h5 style='margin: 20px;'><a href=\"findmusic.php?artist=\"" . $myrow['artist'] . " - "
```

Comment: Отображается, но все ссылки ведут на findmusic.php?artist= :(

Comment: Я Вам дал лишь пример, как вывести информацию. Далее дело за вами. Но дам подсказку: Вы можете request вывести в ваш основной файл, и оттуда всё делать.

Comment: Понял, уже пробую. (:

Comment: Спасибо, на основе вашего скрипта сделал, но, как сделать защиту $_GET в данном случае от ввода любой строчки, после ?artist=? как сделать так, что-бы он определял только те имена, что в базе, а иначе выдавал die?

Comment: перед запросом в артисты, делаете запрос на select артиста из GET, если существует то, идём дальше, а нет == die

Comment: пример селекта можете показать? (: и может, Вы знаете реализацию моего второго вопроса? про месяцы?

Comment: @CryFiX пора включить моз и сделать все самому!

Comment: всё аналогично с месяцами. Обрезаете дату до месяца функцией substr, далее по конструкции if выбираете все январские песни, и далее уже выводите. Всё решать больше ничего не буду, вы должны и свой мозг иметь

Comment: Спасибо и на этом, Дмитрий. Оч благодарен (: